# How to change urlbase setting in Bugzilla config file manually?

Tags: bugzilla

My Bugzilla meets a strange problem. I used my IP as my Bugzilla urlbase setting. So I can login into my Bugzilla by following style address:

`http://192.168.1.146:9090/`

But right now the IP of the machine has been changed, but Bugzilla will still jump to the old address once I login.

Because it is using old address to let me login, so I can't login into administrator page to change the urlbase to new IP.

My question is: where does Bugzilla save the urlbase string? I want to change it manually, so I can relogin my Bugzilla again.

Thanks

Water Lin

Answer (score 14):

Just change the following line in the file `data/params` in the Bugzilla install folder:

```
'urlbase' => 'http://192.168.1.146:9090/',
```

Comment: `params.json` in newer versions